# What are some tools for overcoming bias within a participant when engaged in a Socratic debate?

Tags: logic, epistemology, socrates, debate

Given that bias is not easy to argue with and an embedded unconscious obstacle to critical and logical debate.

What tools are there to overcome bias in a Socratic debate?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. What bias(es) are you talking about?

Comment: @stoicfury the individuals own bias,  not usually conscious, which is why it's difficult

Comment: Bias with regard to what? There are lots of biases in psychology (a field I am quite familiar with); which ones are you referring to here?

Comment: @stoicfury if I specify one particular type of bias in the question, that may put it off topic.. for [cogsci.se] but then maybe that's a good thing..

Comment: Hmm, well I'll put this on hold for now until we can clear things up. It's hard to what you are asking here.

Comment: @stoicfury I think that's a good idea, I'm not well versed enough about philosophy, as I learn I will edit and improve my posts.. I have a history of doing this on [se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguably, if you want to be truly Socratic, you don't debate towards any given goal, you simply ask questions that guide your interlocutee towards greater clarity and understanding of their own ideas and beliefs.

Comment: I actually think this is a really good answer.. it's short, but really is good